# Mount via SSHFS in NFS filesystem

Tags: ssh, nfs, fuse

As a student I have access to a cluster of teaching lab computers, at each of the machines all the home folders (including my) are mounted via NFS. I also have a desktop PC. I want to mount my home folder from the desktop to my home folder at the cluster, so that the freshest version of the source codes was avaiable there. Here is the error I get:

```
 mkdir tmp
 sshfs user@desktop-ip: tmp/

 fusermount: failed to open mountpoint for reading: Stale file handle
```

I don't have admin rights and don't much about mounting. Any ideas what I can do? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Does your desktop PC run a `SSH` server ? If you just need access to latest code, try `git`. Do you have access to `github` or `bitbucket` from your cluster node ?

Comment: Yes, my desktop has a SSH server. I already use git as well, and sshfs was also was made possible by mounting to local folders created by the cluster admin specially for me at each machine. But I leave the question open since it is still unclear what the issue was.

Comment: Can you mount directories of cluster node to your desktop PC ? or to another node of the cluster? Usually `Stale file handler` indicates a network problem.